# Show a message when I submit a form

Tags: javascript, css, node.js, reactjs, next.js

I'm building a site for a project,I have a divided into 50% 50% with display grid, on the right side there is the form, once sent I would like it to show a confirmation or error message , what can I do? i am using nextjs
the form must disappear and show the message

i could use display none, is there a better method? maybe using the components. Thank you

Comment: Have you done a tutorial? https://nextjs.org/docs/guides/building-forms

Comment: @epascarello yes, but I haven't found anything on what I need

Answer (score 0):

Well if it were me, ill create a separate feedback component and once the form is submitted, ill send a response be it an error message or success message.
And maybe add a close button plus a timer to close the component.

Comment: I don't need a timer, I just need to replace the form

Comment: Ok then the form should be a component on its own and after submitting the form, to can swap the form component with the feedback component

Comment: ok thanks, can you give me a code example please?

Answer (score 0):

You can use [React portals](https://reactjs.org/docs/portals.html) to access the right side of your app from the left side and render components in it.

1. I would create a Notification component.

```html
const Notification = ({ message, hideAfterMs }) => {

  const [visible, setVisible] = React.useState(true);

  React.useEffect(() => {
  
    const timeout = setTimeout(() => { setVisible(false); }, hideAfterMs);
  
    return () => {
      clearTimeout(timeout);
    }
  }, [setVisible]);
  
  if(visible)
    return <div>Notification: {message}</div>
    
  return null;
}
```

2. Use the portal to render a notification on the side of your app.